# Please explain what this Javascript syntax is where the object is placed as a parameter in a function declaration

Tags: javascript, object, parameters

I understand functions can be assigned default parameters with the following syntax:

`const Foo = (first = 1) => first + first;`

But in this function grabbed from https://reactcommunity.org/react-transition-group/transition:

```
const Fade = ({ in: inProp }) => (
  <Transition in={inProp} timeout={duration}>
    {(state) => (
      <div style={{
        ...defaultStyle,
        ...transitionStyles[state]
      }}>
        I'm a fade Transition!
      </div>
    )}
  </Transition>
);
```

...I cannot figure out what the `{ in: inProp }` is supposed to be in the function declaration.

I know `inProp` is being used by the prop `in` inside `Transition`, but why aren't we using: `const Fade = (inProp) => <Transition in={inProp} timeout={duration}>` instead?

Nowhere do I see `in` being referenced other than the prop section of `Transition`, but I'm pretty sure those aren't the same literal variable.

I have searched for all sorts of terms, including searching Symbol Hound, and cannot find what this is called or what it's doing.

Comment: Parameter destructuring https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Unpacking_fields_from_objects_passed_as_function_parameter meaning `(obj) => { let inProp = obj.in; …`.

Comment: `in` is the name of one of the fields inside the object being passed to the `Transition` component  function. `inProp` specifies a new variable name for `in` to be used in the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`in` is the name of a field/key in the object being passed to the `Transition` component function (this is probably handled by the library you're using). `inProp` specifies a new variable name for `in` to be used in the function.

So the incoming argument to the function is an object that has this shape at a minimum:

```
{
  in: "A value"
}
```

You could rename that `in` key to a `newName` and use it like so:

```
const Fade = ({ in: newName }) => (
  <Transition in={newName} timeout={duration}>
    {(state) => (
      <div style={{
        ...defaultStyle,
        ...transitionStyles[state]
      }}>
        I'm a fade Transition!
      </div>
    )}
  </Transition>
);
```

Or you could avoid renaming the name of the object key and use it as is like so:

```
const Fade = ({ in }) => (
  <Transition in={in} timeout={duration}>
    {(state) => (
      <div style={{
        ...defaultStyle,
        ...transitionStyles[state]
      }}>
        I'm a fade Transition!
      </div>
    )}
  </Transition>
);
```

Answer (score 3):

It is [parameter unpacking](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Unpacking_fields_from_objects_passed_as_function_parameter).

Two examples:

```js
function getSecond({two}) {
  document.write(two);
}

function getFirst({one: first}) { // this notation "renames" the property
  document.write(first);
}

obj = {
  one: 'First',
  two: 'Second',
  three: 'Third'
};

getSecond(obj);
document.write(', ');
getFirst(obj);
```

---

So in your case, somewhere some code calls the function `Fade` like this:

```
Fade({
  property: value,
  // ...
  in: ... ,
  // ...
});
```

And your function accepts an object like this as its argument, and extracts specifically its `in` property, but renames it (locally) to `inProp`.

Answer (score 0):

The parameter in the Fade function is not a default parameter. It is actually an object destructuring.

> The destructuring assignment syntax is a JavaScript expression that makes it possible to unpack values from arrays, or properties from objects, into distinct variables.

[MDN Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Unpacking_fields_from_objects_passed_as_function_parameter)

An easy way to think about object destructuring is that it is like putting an object literal (`{ key: value }`), where you would usually put a variable name.

This means that

```
const { propA, propB } = obj
```

is equvalent to

```
const propA = obj.propA;
const propB = obj.propB;
```

and in your example

```
({ in: inProp }) => { ... }
```

is the same as

```
(arg) => {
  const inProp = arg.in;
  ...
}
```